# Check picturebox image

Tags: c#, if-statement, picturebox

I am making a c# puzzle game, but I've got a problem.

```
if (pictureBox1.Image == Properties.Resources._1)
    pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources._2;
```

The if statement seems to be false all the time. what could be the problem?

Comment: You are testing for [**reference equality**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183752.aspx). Unless you've previously done `pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources._1`, your comparisons will always be false.

Comment: A Properties.Resources.XxxxYyy property will always return a new bitmap every time you use it.  In general a nasty source of ballooning memory usage.  You have to store it in a variable in your form constructor, now you can compare it.